# Rendering a array retrieve from a promise service to the page is pretty slow. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a small project with angular 4, and I am trying to retrieve data from google firebase. **The brief description of this project's architecture is:**

**app-component:** inject a login service using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` to distinguish if the user is able to login or not. When login success, it will be redirected to the home-component.

**home-component:**  inject a company service, and using `firebase.database().ref().child("COMPANY").once("value")` to get data from firebase.

However, when I retrieve the data (an object array) from firebase, and pass to the variable bind to the html page, it renders the array **VERY SLOWLY**. It costs 30 sec. or more to display data on the page.

If I did something wrong? Or how come the performance was so terrible?

---

Here is the code slice:

```
HomeComponent.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanyService } from '../Service/CompanyService';
@Component({
....
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   companies : Object[];
   constructor(private service : CompanyService) { 
   }
   ngOnInit() {
     this.service.getAllData()
         .then((result : Object[]) => { 
                this.companies = result;
                //this.companies = [ { "CODE": "APTG", "NAME": "APTG Inc." }, { "CODE": "CHT", "NAME": "CHT Inc." }, { "CODE": "FET", "NAME": "FET Inc." }, { "CODE": "T STAR", "NAME": "T STAR Inc." }, { "CODE": "TWM", "NAME": "TWM Inc." } ];
          })
          .catch((error : any) => {
                console.log("error=",error);
          });
       }     
}
```

---

```
CompanyService.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Promise } from 'es6-promise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'; 
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

    constructor(private http:Http){

    }

    db : any = firebase.database().ref();

    getAllData(){

      return this.db.child("COMPANY")
                        .once("value")
                        .then(function(snapshot){

                          return Promise.resolve(snapshot.val());
                        })
                        .catch(function(error){

                          return Promise.reject(error);

                        });                   

    }

}
```

---

```
HomeComponent.html

{{companies | json}}
```

Comment: import ChangeDetectorRef from @angular/core and use this code just after this.companies = result; line:
this.changeDetector.detectChanges()